# How to use my JSON file to build a NoSQL database?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, nosql

I have a JSON file which is 3000+ lines. What I'd like to do is create a NoSQL database with the same structure (it has embedded documents between 3-5 levels deep). But I want to add information to each level and create a schema for each item, so that I can go back at a later stage and update the information fields, and even have users log-in and change their own values.

I am using JavaScript to write a script that will iterate through the file and upload to MongoDB the schema that I want, based on the information at each level. But I'm struggling to write the code that does this efficiently. At this stage, I'm just wasting too much time trying this and that, and want to move on to the next step of my site.

Below is an example of the file. Basically, it's a bunch of embedded documents, and then at the final level (which will be at a different depth depending on which document it's in), there is an array where each of the fields is a string.

How can I use this data to create a MongoDB database while adding a schema to each item, but keeping the hierarchical nature of the documents? I want all of the documents to have one schema, and then each of the strings at the final depth to have their own, separate schema as well. I can't think of an efficient way to iterate through.

Example from the JSON file:

```
{
"Applied Sciences": {
    "Agriculture": {
        "Agricultural Economics": [
            "Agricultural Environment And Natural Resources",
            "Developmental Economics",
            "Food And Consumer Economics",
            "Production Economics And Farm Management"
            ],
        "Agronomy": [
            "Agroecology",
            "Biotechnology",
            "Plant Breeding",
            "Soil Conservation",
            "Soil Science",
            "Theoretical Modeling"
            ],
```

Here's my schema for all but the strings at the end:

```
name: String,
completed: Boolean,
category: "Field",
items: {
    type: Array
    },
description: String,
resources: {
    type: Array
    }
};
```

And my rough code which at this stage just iterates through. I'm trying to use the same function call to create the Arrays in the schema, but I'm just not up to that stage yet because I can't even iterate properly through:

```
function createDatabase(data){  
    for (field in data){
        items = {};
        for (field in data){
            if (typeof data[field] == "object");
            items[field] = createDatabase(data[field]);
        };
    return items;
    }
```

Comment: I Think you need to model the data first.  which I prefer do with Attribute pattern it help to run efficient search and index after that try to make schema.

Comment: Maybe show us at least some of your code. Perhaps you are not aware some nice functions in Javascript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit https://stackoverflow.com/users/20306839/naveen 
I have just edited my original post with more info.